# How to make sublime refer to the active Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext2

I downloaded python via macports and I am currently running code via Sublime Text 2.

When I run a code, for instance, the code has

```
import matplotlib
```

Sublime is giving me this error:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

But when I type `import matplotlib` in python using terminal, it doesn't give me such error. I know it is referring to the wrong python.

I need to change Sublime to point to the current active python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution solved it for me:

1 - Open Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse Packages

2 - Go to the Python folder, select file Python.sublime-build

3 - Replace the existing cmd line for this one:

```
"cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python", "$file"],
```

Then click CMD+B and your script with matplotlib stuff will work.